# How do I check system specifications?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware, system

I am total noob in Linux. I wanna know what is the equivalent of "My Computer" in Ubuntu 11.04. I want to check my computer specs such as Processor Speed, Memory, and etc.

Whenever I check properties in Home Folder it only gives me the HD capacity. I also tried looking at System Settings but I can't find it there. Please help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Super</kbd> (Start button in windows) , Type and and open `System Monitor`.

[image]

---

For full details system information use **HardInfo** : [Click to install.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hardinfo)

**HardInfo can display information about both your system's hardware and operating system.**

[image]

Comment: Does HardInfo tell me about my computer's graphics properties, like video drivers, etc?

Comment: This answer does not work anymore in Ubuntu 15.10. There is no Tab System in System Monitor anymore. I opened a new thread about the situation here http://askubuntu.com/q/715949/25388

Comment: I think this needs to be updated. It's no longer valid. Lubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 67):

for command line solutions, you can use the command lshw.

Install it if needed:

```
sudo apt-get install lshw
```

then run something like

```
sudo lshw -html > mySpecs.html
```

then check the html file.

Comment: I corrected my answer, since "sysinfo" is not even used.

Comment: seems its part of Ubuntu package now and you do not need to install it.

Answer (score 27):

This should give you what you need:

```
lshw | less
```

On ec2 14.04 I found lshw is pre-installed, so I am going to assume it's part of Ubuntu 14.04 package now and you do not need to explicitly install it.

Comment: `lshw` means ls(list) hw(hardware)

Answer (score 16):

If you cannot install **lshw**, you can try the following:

- **lscpu**: list CPU and processor info
- **hwinfo**: generic hardware information
- **lspci**: PCI busses, including graphics card, network adapter
- **lsblk**: list block devices (storage and partitions)
- **df -h**: disk free
- **free -h**: total, free, used RAM

**neofetch** (`apt install neofetch`) also provides info in a nice screenshotable form like CPU, GPU, memory installed, and OS.

Answer (score 12):

WEB UPD8 has a detail guide on this topic.

[How To Get Hardware Information In Linux | Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-get-hardware-information-in.html)

In short, you could use lshw (command-line or gtk), hardinfo, sysinfo to get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

`inxi` is a command line tool that can be used to find the complete system and hardware details. The `inxi` command below will show you all the possible system and hardware information on Linux:

```bsh
inxi -Fxz
```

Answer (score 2):

run `sudo lshw -html > server_specs.html` 
the html result is well structured and easy to find information.

also you can use `sudo lshw -C {required_type}` to see result for your required specification. for example `sudo lshw -C memory`

Answer (score 1):

A user on the Ubuntu Forums ([MAFoElffen](https://github.com/Mafoelffen1)) has created a `system-info` script for the official Ubuntu Forums.

This script uses various system commands (such as `lscpu`, `hwinfo`, `lspci`, `lsblk` etc.) to generate a detailed report of all relevant information.

The script can be installed and run by going to the directory where you want to install the script, and then run the following:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/raw/main/system-info && \
chmod +x system-info && \
./system-info
```

This will download the script, make it executable, and then run it.

From the official description on the [Github page](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info):

> - Creates the file `system-info.txt` at the base of the user's home directory.
> - Masks all sensitive info, like IP addresses, MAC addresses, Full FQDN and Serial numbers, automatically in a meaningful way.
> - The script displays the report results within the 'less' utility to review the results, one screen at a time. To navigate from there,
>   press the space bar, left, right, up, down, page up or page down keys
>   to navigate. If in a graphical terminal session, you can also use
>   mouse navigation. Press the "q" key to exit "less" and continue. It
>   will print the final report and offer to upload to pastebin site.
> - Offers to post the results to the Ubuntu `pastebinit` provider if that program is installed, and a sufficiently reliable internet
>   connection is available. This is the easiest way to share the
>   sanitized results with the Ubuntu Community for support. After
>   succssful upload to the pastebin, it will both display and log the URL
>   of the uploaded report (`~/system-info-link.log`), for you to copy and
>   paste in your post on the Ubuntu Forums.
> - Future versions may have an option to create the archive `system-info.tar.gz` if the report exceeds 19.5 kB in size.

Running this script is advised before diagnosing system issue on the Ubuntu Forum, and it could also find a similar use here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings. Then Go to Details.

[image]