# Desktop always in Ubuntu Classic mode

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gnome-classic

My friend installed Ubuntu 11.04. We are pretty sure it's Ubuntu 11.04. He looked at about Ubuntu zone. 
THe problem is that the desktop is always like Ubuntu Classic. When logging, i said; change the ubuntu classic to ubuntu. However he said it's already Ubuntu.
BTW he says my gnome version is 2.32 maybe 2.34.
What we can do?

Comment: its very likely to be a graphics issue - what graphics card does your friend have and have they installed any Additional Drivers?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your friend's system info as well. You can do so by following this guide. http://askubuntu.com/questions/55609/how-do-i-check-system-specifications

Comment: JFYI, if a system couldn't support Unity, it will 'fallback' to the Ubuntu Classic.

Comment: We found that his pc does not support requirement. It's solved.

Comment: Please make an answer specifying which requirement the PC didn't support for future reference.

Comment: we run this command in the terminal

Comment: We run this comman in terminal: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p              And in a line named "unity supported", it was no.

Answer (score 1):

*As per the comments that were left*

It is not compatible with the Unity Interface, as such it reverts to the normal GNOME2 desktop.