# How do I check system specifications in 15.10?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware

The accepted answer of the thread [How do I check system specifications?](https://askubuntu.com/q/55609/25388) is about System Monitor > System in 11.04.
However, there is no tab *System* anymore in the application System Monitor of Ubuntu 15.10. 
I still want to do the checking by default tools, not by external installations.

How can you check system specifications in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: The accepted answer also proposes another method, and there are other answers on that question, doesn't any of the other proposed methods avail?

Comment: Then you should have pointed that out in your question, as you can see not having done that attracted an answer unuseful to solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find some info under System Settings > Details > Overview.
It gives you some details about your RAM, Processor, OS Type and hardrive.

[image: Overview]

If you want something more complete you can install hardinfo via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install hardinfo
```

It gives you a very complete description about your system.

[image: HardInfo]

Have a nice day!