# How can I check the details of my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 16.04

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
How do I check if it has installed 16.04 LTS?
What is its name?
Release Date?
Expiry Date?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @mondjunge why is it unclear? it is clear to me

Comment: Related: for hardware info see https://askubuntu.com/questions/55609/how-do-i-check-system-specifications/393594

Comment: Please clarify: "I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. How do I check if it has installed 16.04 LTS?"

Answer (score 6):

You can find out what version of Ubuntu you are running from various ways. 
Open the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type `lsb_release -a` to give you details of your Ubuntu.

Terminal output for mine:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

You can also run `uname -a`, which will give a little more complicated but understandable information. (For help with the command type in the terminal `man uname` or `uname --help`.)

Terminal output for mine:

```
Linux tony-Inspiron-7559 4.4.0-45-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 15:05:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Also, you can head to Settings and look for `Details` or `About This Computer` and that can give you details of your distribution.

[image: details]

As for End of Life (EOL), the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) has a list of current and end of life distros, and full details of support dates, periods, docs of distros etc.

Here is a quick reference from the site, a table that decribes the suport life of each version of Ubuntu:

[image: lifesuport_ubuntu]

Comment: Could you crop your terminal screenshots? Or even better, paste them as text?

Comment: @Melebius I added the terminal output and some extra info. Thanks for the suggestion. :D

Answer (score 5):

In terminal type:

```
lsb_release -a
```

You will get for example:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Information about release dates/expiry you can get for example here.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases