# Where do I find the system specifications on Xubuntu GUI, equivalent to the System Monitor?

Tags: xubuntu

I'd like to find the system specifications from the **GUI** (not via lshw).

According to [this source](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-ubuntu-and-xubuntu/) Xubuntu is just a slim version of Ubuntu.

> Xubuntu is a permutation of the Ubuntu software. It is a combination
> of the Xfce (Xforms common environment) and the Ubuntu operating
> system. [...] This permutation uses Xfce as the graphical desktop, and
> has an added focus of utilising a low memory footprint. [...]  Xubuntu
> updates are released every two years – their release coinciding with
> Ubuntu update releases. Thus, Xubuntu uses the same version numbers
> and code names as Ubuntu.

Assuming the systems are fairly the same, I followed the instructions provided in [this ask ubuntu entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55609/how-do-i-check-system-specifications):

> Hit `Super` (Start button in windows) , Type and and open `System Monitor`.

This did however not work for me.

`System Monitor` doesn't seem to exist.

My version is:

```
me@me: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20/04
Codename:       focal
```

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: You have me confused you asked about XUbuntu but that info says you are running Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Your link is old and not applicable to newer Ubuntu releases. As above, I'm confused, your says Ubuntu, not XUbuntu. If you actually have Ubuntu then at system settings > About you'll find the same information shown in your link.

Comment: @David - yes that is apparently how Xubuntu works: Upon startup - I see the Xubuntu logo but when checking lsb_release -a it shows Ubuntu. Citing from [this source](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-ubuntu-and-xubuntu/): 

"Xubuntu is a permutation of the Ubuntu software. It is a combination of the Xfce (Xforms common environment) and the **Ubuntu operating system**. [...]This permutation uses Xfce as the graphical desktop, and has an added focus of utilising a low memory footprint. **Xubuntu** uses the **same version numbers** and **code names as Ubuntu**."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One you can try is `hardinfo`.

```
sudo apt install hardinfo
```

Then it can be found in *Xue Menu -> System -> System Profiler and Benchmark*

[image]

Comment: Good one Terrance :) Probably a lot easier on the eyes too.